# Dependency injection switch between implementations

Tags: angular, angular2-di

I've got an app that's working in two different modes: demonstration and normal. The demo mode is only used when the user does not have an account and only wants to try the app to see how it works.

Now suppose that we have a service that's used in the app. For instance a service to retrieve an `Account` and authenticate a user:

```
abstract class AccountService {
  authenticate(username: string, password: string): Observable<Boolean>;
  getAccount(): Observable<Account>;
}
```

For this service we have two implementations, one for each mode. `AccountServiceImpl`, for the normal mode, performs an HTTP request to some server to retrieve the account. While the `AccountServiceDemoImpl` simply returns a hardcoded one.

Suppose we have an `AccountComponent` component that shows the account name to the user. For this component it does not matter which of the implementations we're using, so we just inject an `AccountService` in its constructor.

All is good and well, and we can easily use either of the implementations to fill out the AccountComponent. Now we want to be able to switch between these implementations at runtime when the user clicks a button on the login page. So I wrote a factory provider to determine which AccountService implementation to use

```
{provide: AccountService, deps[AccountServiceImpl, AccountServiceDemoImpl], (regularService, demoService) => demoModeActivated ? demoService : regularService}
```

As you can imagine, the `AccountService` is also injected on the login page to deal with the authentication of the user. Which means that the factory has already been evaluated. Now, the problem is that the result of this evaluation is cached in Angular. So when the demo mode is activated and the user navigates to the `AccountComponent`, the actual `AccountServiceImpl` will be injected again.

Is there a way to clear the DI cache (for a specific set of DI tokens)? Or should I try to deal with this feature in another way? (For instance, write another implementation of the `AccountService` that delegates to either the `AccountServiceImpl` or the `AccountServiceDemoImpl`.)

Comment: You can't. This is XY problem. Please, provide the details why exactly you need this in order to get a proper answer.

Comment: @estus, could you please elaborate on what information you're missing. Based on some value at runtime, I want to be able to inject one or the other implementation of `MyService`. This runtime value will change when an instance of `MyService` has already been injected. Since it has already been injected at least once, the mapping from `MyService => MyServiceImpl` will be cached in angular's DI system. So from that point onwards, angular will always inject the `MyServiceImpl` whenever a `MyService` is required

Comment: Please, explain what you need it for and how you intend to use it. What is your case. There's nothing to discuss as long as it stays abstract 'service', it just cannot be done.

Comment: It's like the answer explains. A good alternative would probably be facade class that wraps both DemoService and RegularService and switches between them on condition (demoModeActivated value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially it would seem that a factory provider would solve this for you. Unfortunately factory revolvers are synchronous and you are relying on an asynchronous call to determine which service to provide.

Instead you can use a Resolve guard. Within the resolve method you would return an observable that calls the auth method and then maps to newing up either service. And then calls the first() operator to complete the observable after its first go.

It resolve guards seem to have been designed to return simple DTO structures, not services. But this works.

Instead of newing up instances, you can inject both services in the Resolve Guard and map to either one, in the case you want this service to remain a singleton.

```
export class AccountServiceResolver implements Resolve<AccountService> {

  constructor(private accountService: AccountService, demmoService: AccountDemoService) { }

  resolve(): Observable<AccountService> {

    return this.accountService.getAccount().map(account => {

      if (account.real) {
        return this.accountService;
      } else {
        return this.demoService;
      }
    }).first();
  }

}
```

Then get this in your component:

```
ngOnInit(route: ActivatedRoute) {

  const service = route.data[0];
}
```